# How to check if each <book> element has a specific subchild in xml file

Tags: python, xml, python-3.7, elementtree

I want to validate my XML file to check if every `<book>` element has a sub-child of `<target>` and throw error if any is missing.

My XML looks like this:

```
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:2.0"  version="2.0"><course id="cr1"><book id="bk1"><dek><source>ssf</source><target>ssf</target></dek></book>
<book id="bk2"><dek><source>ssf</source><target>ssf</target></dek></book>
<book id="bk3"><dek><source>ssf</source><target>ssf</target></dek></book>
<book id="bk4"><dek><source>ssf</source><target>ssf</target></dek></book>
</course>
<course id="cr2"><book id="bk1"><dek><source>ssf</source><target>ssf</target></dek></book>
<book id="bk2"><dek><source>ssf</source><target>ssf</target></dek></book>
<book id="bk3"><dek><source>ssf</source><target>ssf</target></dek></book>
<book id="bk4"><dek><source>ssf</source><target>ssf</target></dek></book>
</course>
</xliff>
```

Can someone advice me how to proceed this with etree.ElementTree

I tried with this, is it possible to do it in one call?

```
   count_books = len(tree.findall(".//books"))
   count_target = len(tree.findall(".//target"))
   if (count_books != count_target):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ElementTree's XPath support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) is very limited, so I don't think you can do it with a single `findall` call.

If you can switch to lxml, you could use `xpath()` and do it in a single call...

```py
from lxml import etree

xml = """<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:2.0"  version="2.0"><course id="cr1"><book id="bk1"><dek><source>ssf</source><target>ssf</target></dek></book>
<book id="bk2"><dek><source>ssf</source><target>ssf</target></dek></book>
<book id="bk3"><dek><source>ssf</source><target>ssf</target></dek></book>
<book id="bk4"><dek><source>ssf</source><target>ssf</target></dek></book>
</course>
<course id="cr2"><book id="bk1"><dek><source>ssf</source><target>ssf</target></dek></book>
<book id="bk2"><dek><source>ssf</source><target>ssf</target></dek></book>
<book id="bk3"><dek><source>ssf</source><target>ssf</target></dek></book>
<book id="bk4"><dek><source>ssf</source><target>ssf</target></dek></book>
</course>
</xliff>
"""

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)

ns = {"x": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:2.0"}

bad_books = tree.xpath('.//x:book[not(.//x:target)]', namespaces=ns)

print(f"Are there any book elements without a target? - {bool(bad_books)}")
```

This will return:

```
Are there any book elements without a target? - False
```

with the current input. If you remove a `target` (or rename it), it will return:

```
Are there any book elements without a target? - True
```